# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser get user input and grab value from web page and return that value

Tags: php, ajax, getelementbyid, simple-html-dom

I have php page where the user can enter the mutual fund ticker symbol.

I am trying to enable the user to click a button and have the name of the fund display of the page.

I assume that I need to pass the value from the input box to a separate php page. I have a php page that uses php simple html dom parser and if I hard code the ticker symbol the php page will extract the name of the fund from a web page.

I am not clear on the concept of how I pass the variable from the input box to the the other php file or whether I even need a separate php file.

Is it possible to keep this all on the same php page? Right now, on the separate php page, I have a variable that holds the fund name.

I'm not sure how to display that value on the first php page.
If somebody could help me with the concept, I can write some code.

Below is the page named `getFundName.php` which gets the fund name.

```
<?php
      include('simple_html_dom.php');
      $firstvar = "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/";
      $secondvar = "LLPFX";
      $combovar = $firstvar . $secondvar;

      $html = new simple_html_dom();
      $html->load_file($combovar); 

      $getFundName = $html->find('#instrumentname',0);
      print_r($getFundName->plaintext);
      //echo $getFundName->plaintext;
      $html->clear(); 
      unset($html);
?>
Below is my guess at the other code, but obviously it's not functioning.

<?php
     some php code here
?>
<html>
   <body>
      <script language="JavaScript">
            function getFundName() { 
              var xhr=createXHR();
              xhr.open("GET", "getFundName.php",true);
              xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
              { 
                  if(xhr.readyState == 4)
                  {
                     document.getElementById("displayFundNameHere").innerHTML= xhr.responseText;    
                  } 
              };
        }
     </script>
  <div id="displayFundNameHere"><div>
   Fund Symbol: <input type="text" id='fundSymbolBox'/>
   <input type="button" value="Get Fund Name" onclick="getFundName()"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to want to do is setup the page to take input, and do an AJAX request to a PHP page which will return the data you want.

Looking at your code, you seem most of the way there, don't forget that you need to call `xhr.send()` after you assign your callback.

If you wanted to keep it all on the same page, you could wrap everything in a form which posts to itself and have the PHP code pull out the data from the POST variable and fill in the data without using AJAX or javascript.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I will work with that and see if I can get something working.